# How to implement Pagination Rails Rest

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to implement on Angular 2 pagination but I do not know how to write in controller and in routes on rails. Who can explain how to write controller and routes correctly? 
Here is part of my code controller and routes:

Controller:

```
 ...
 def index
    @spr_bit_types = SprBitType.all
    render json: @spr_bit_types
 end

 def show
    render json: @spr_bit_type
 end

 def page 
    @page = params [: page] 
    @pre_page = params [: pre_page]
 end
 ...
```

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :spr_bit_types, only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy]
  map.connect 'spr_bit_types / page /: page',: controller => 'spr_bit_types',: action =>' page '
  ...
end
```

This part of the code does not work at all: **map.connect 'spr_bit_types / page /: page',: controller => 'spr_bit_types',: action =>' page '**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`api-pagination`](https://github.com/davidcelis/api-pagination) gem

and then you can simply write following code

```
def index
  @spr_bit_types = SprBitType.all
  paginate json: @spr_bit_types
end

def show
  paginate json: @spr_bit_type
end
```